# Another way of showing that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

This is a question from an old paper exam, where the ultimate goal is to prove that
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
There are a lot of answers to that question, and I believe I've seen most of then, but none following the argument given in this problem (despite some similarities).
The question is divided in three parts:

> **Question 1:** Show that, for $x>0$,
>   $$\frac{1}{x} = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}dt$$

This I believe is can be proved just by integrating. Since $\int e^{-xt}dt= -\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}+K$, 
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt}dt = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-xt} - \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0 - \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$
Now:

> **Question 2:** Show that, if $A>0$, the function $[0,A]\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(x,t)\mapsto \sin x\, e^{-xt}$ is integrable in $[0,A]\times[0,\infty)$.

I am not sure if what I've done here is correct, but this is my attempt:
$$\int_0^A \int_0^{\infty}\sin x\, e^{-xt}dt\ dx = \int_0^{\infty}\sin x \left(\int_0^A e^{-xt} dt \right) dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$
where interchanging the integral is (I think) justified by Tonelli's theorem, and now the function integrable since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is continuous in $[0, \infty)$.

The last question asks the following:

> **Question 3:** Use Question 1, Question 2 and Fubini's Theorem to show that
>   \begin{align}
>  \int_0^A \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2} + \int_0^{\infty}g_A(t)dt, \, A>0   \tag{1}
> \end{align}
>   where
>   $$\left \vert \int_0^{\infty}g_A(t)dt\right\vert \leq \frac{K}{A},$$
>   and $K$ is some constant, and deduce that
>   $$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_0^A \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I see how the result follows from $(1)$, but I don't have any ideas on how to get to that equation. Some help regarding that would be helpful.

Comment: You made a mistake. It meant for $A$ finite $\int_0^A \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \int_0^A \sin x\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt}dt\ dx =\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\infty} 1_{x \in [0,A]} \sin x \ e^{-xt}dt\ dx\\ =\int_0^\infty (\int_0^{\infty} 1_{x \in [0,A]} \sin x \, e^{-xt}dx)\ dt = \ldots$

Comment: In Q2, ir is crucial to show absolute convergence, that is, that $$\int_0^A\int_0^\infty|\sin x\cdot e^{-xt}|\,dtdx$$ is finite.

Comment: @reuns I am not sure I'm understanding correctly what you wrote. Why write $1_{x\in [0, A]}$? Is it necessary or can I just work with $\int_0^A \int_0^{\infty} \sin x \ e^{-xt} dx$ instead?

Comment: @Did Thank you for the remark! That should follow from $|\sin x| \leq x$ and $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}dt = 1/x$, right? With that I get $$\int_0^A \int_0^{\infty} |\sin x \ e^{-xt}| dt dx = \int_0^A \frac{|\sin x|}{x}dx \leq A$$

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @user313212 Sure $\int_0^\infty (\int_0^{\infty} 1_{x \in [0,A]} \sin x \, e^{-xt}dx)\ dt = \int_0^\infty (\int_0^A \sin x \, e^{-xt}dx)\ dt = \ldots$. Compare with what you wrote in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^A \frac {\sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^A \int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sin x\ dt\ dx = \int_0^\infty\int_0^A e^{-xt}\sin x\  dx\ dt\\
\int_0^\infty -\frac {e^{-xt}(\cos x + t\sin x)}{1+t^2}|_0^A dt\\
\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+t^2} - \frac {e^{-At}(\cos A + t \sin A)}{1+t^2}\ dt\\
\frac {\pi}{2} + \int_0^\infty g(A,t)\ dt$

Now we need to show that $\int_0^\infty g(A,t) \ dt$ is bounded as described above.

$|\frac {\cos A + t\sin A}{1+t^2}| < |\cos A + \sin A| < \sqrt 2$

alternatively

$|\frac {\cos A + t\sin A}{1+t^2}| < \frac {1 + t}{1+t^2} \le \frac 12 + \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$

$|\int_0^\infty g(A,t)\ dt| < \int_0^{\infty} \sqrt 2 e^{-At}\ dt =\frac {\sqrt 2}{A}$

Comment: Thanks! The part when you go from $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^A e^{-xt}\sin x dx dt$ to $\int_0^{\infty} - \frac{e^{-xt}(\cos x + t\sin x)}{1+t^2}\vert_0^A dt$ is obtained by setting $F(t) = \int_0^A e^{-xt} \frac{\sin x}{x}dt$ and then differentiate to get $F'(t)$, right?